# About the validation in web application development

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is client-side validation not enough ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483514/why-is-client-side-validation-not-enough)

you have to validate data before store it.

validate in client side or server side or both?

what's your consideration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is client-side validation not enough ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483514/why-client-side-validation-is-not-enough)

Comment: Given the referenced question, this question is becomes basically, `why not just server-side validation?`

Answer (score 5):

My consideration: both.

1. client-side - more user-friendly (e.g can respond right after leaving the field, no full-page reload, quicker response since no roundtrip network request, etc)
2. server-side - because [you shouldn't trust the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483514/why-client-side-validation-is-not-enough)

The drawback is of course maintaining the rules in both places, especially if they are in different languages/frameworks.