# Validation does not work in Firefox, works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, validation, firefox

I have an email validation code on client side. It works fine/as expected in IE but somehow doesnot show error messages in Firefox.

Below is the code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnLink" runat="server" AlternateText="ClickHere" OnClientClick="return onCClick();" OnClick="btnLink_Click"/>  
<div id="errorEmail" runat="server"></div>
```

---

```
//function to validate
        function onCClick() {
//clear error message
            document.getElementById('<%=errorEmail.ClientID%>').innerText = "";
//if validation fails
            if (validateEmail() != true) {
//show error message
                document.getElementById('<%=errorEmail.ClientID%>').innerText = "Invalid Email Address.";
                return false;
            }
}

function validateEmail() {
            var emailId = document.getElementById('<%=txtEmail.ClientID%>').value;
            var emailPattern = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
            return emailPattern.test(emailId);
        }
```

Is there something which i should have taken care of ? My error message div is set to blank but not invisible anywhere(in that case javascript also would not have worked)

Comment: possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: I don't see any reference to the errorEmailAddress `div`. Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: it's recommended to use `jQuery` as it's cross browsers

Comment: @MahmoudFarahat:  May be yes, but will have to change whole code :( and all other validations as well. That too as of now I am not sure if that will work.

Comment: @epascarello : Thanks for pointer. Never knew if exactly the issue was with innerText or my way of calling or my function. Thanks for pointer, will try out suggestions from that solution.

Comment: Just a reminder, any validation you're doing on the client side should also be done on the server side. [Never trust the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483514/why-is-client-side-validation-not-enough).

Comment: Thanks @probackpacker - Good point.

Answer (score 1):

`innerText` is not cross browser, firefox uses `textContent`

You can use a function like this:

```
function changeText(elem, changeVal) {
    if ((elem.textContent) && (typeof (elem.textContent) != "undefined")) {
        elem.textContent = changeVal;
    } else {
        elem.innerText = changeVal;
    }
}
```

or just use `innerHTML`.

Comment: trying my best. Works in IE not in FF :(

Comment: Code should work with the swap to innerHTML. Make sure to clear the cache in case you are cached.

Answer (score 0):

Better you try innerHTML.. it will work..

```
document.getElementById('errorEmailAddress').innerHTML = "Error Message";
```

Comment: throws exception: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object