# Accept image by URL

Tags: php, image

I got input in my website, The input is suppose to get image URL, What is want to validate is:

1. Am i getting an image?
2. Is it 64x64?
3. Image type png/jpg/gif/etc?

The best solution for **All** the terms above i was thinking about is [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

If anyone can think of more terms for validating and better solution i will be very thankfull, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first ,

You could use `getimagesize()` which returns zeros for size on non-images.

For the second,

```
$imageName = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imageName);
```

you can check condition with `$width` and `$height`

For the third,

```
$imageName = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($imageName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);// alternative method
```

You could use `$type` from second to check `extention`

With `$ext` you can check `extention` of image

Here is link for you http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/25.html

So in altogether you could simply use `getimagesize()` for these 3 conditions

Comment: My database i storing the URL I am not uploading the image, Do you think i should upload it?.

Comment: If it is in database, just specify the `url` in `$imageName` retrieved from database

Comment: I understand what you mean but, Do you think i should upload the images to my server?

Comment: If you need to validate before uploading to server, you could do it with client side scripts

Comment: I can, But if some one turn JS off, I should always add server side validation.

Comment: It is better to validate with server script as well, check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855770/why-do-we-need-both-client-side-and-server-side-validation

Answer (score 2):

this is php code for checking format (say www.example.com/image.png)

```
$url = "some url";
$format = substr($url , -3);
if($format == "png" || $format == "jpg" || $format == "gif")
    print "right";
else
    print "wrong";
```

Comment: Thank you mamal, I will wait for more solutions.

Comment: Note that this may not necessarily always work; I could take a `.gif` and rename it to `.jpg` for example.