# jQuery .on() shortcut syntax vs delegation

Tags: jquery, syntax, delegation

**This one is about a coding syntax ( a shortcut? ) that I just found**.

I really got mystified with [**this `.on()` syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623997/2159528) last week.

The main use I was doing of `.on()`, until now, was to delegate event(s) on dynamically added elements.

Like so:

```
$("[selector]").on("[event,event,event,...]","[delegate selector]",function(){
    //... Something.
});
```

This is a common use to bind **ONE** handler from a collection to another (dynamic child) regarding one or many events.

**But**, now that I know about the existance of [**this `.on()` syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40623997/2159528)...
Which is more "event-specific" and really allows to be more concise in code writing:

```
$("[selector]").on({
    [event]:function(){
        //...Something
    },
    [event]:function(){
        //...Something else.
    }
});
```

I see this *(new for me!)* syntax as providing an object as argument to `.on()`.
Even many objects, coma separated.

It is wonderfully binding specific handlers to a collection, regarding numerous events.
I think it's a real efficient way to code... And readability is great.

## But now...

**How to delegate the events from an "onloaded" selector to a dynamically appended child using this syntax?**

Is it possible ?
Please, tell me yes and show me how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to delegate the events from an "onloaded" selector to a dynamically appended child using this syntax?

The syntax you are looking for is this:

```
$('staticParentElement').on({
    [event]:function(){
        //...Something
    },
    [event]:function(){
        //...Something else.
    }
}, 'dynamicDescendants');
```

Comment: Only an *"undefined"* SO user could have answered to this!